# How do I build a debug configuration of a Plutus project?

Tags: plutus, cabal, haskell, plutustx

When I try to set a breakpoint in a small Plutus project such as [this](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/tree/c1dc67e8d4e681cccd3cb83e48f8c313477305c6/code/week05), I always get the following error:

```
:b Week05.Homework1.mkPolicy
cannot set breakpoint on Week05.Homework1.mkPolicy: module Week05.Homework1 is not interpreted
```

(Using Windows, cabal version 3.4.0.0, ghc version 8.10.4.)

Removing `-fobject-code` or adding `-fPIC` to the ghc-options won't help, which was suggested [here for other Haskell projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570367/debugging-io-in-a-package-module-inside-ghci). `-fPIC` does even fail as it is [not a Windows thing](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2015-08/msg00836.html), anyway.

The error is the same for off- and on-chain functions. So the `INLINABLE` pragma is not to blame.

Does this have anything to do with the [PlutusTx compiler](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/02/02/plutus-tx-compiling-haskell-into-plutus-core/)?

Comment: This may have to do with Haskell being a functional language. Meaning that unlike imperative languages, there are no 'breakpoints' due to the nature of the language. The other link you mentioned only works with I/O operations which follow an 'imperative' style. The answer for your question would be to find a new way to debug functional programs, seeing as they don't work with imperative style debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`mkPolicy` is an on-chain validator code, is lifted to template Haskell and it gets compiled to core plutus and executed when the UTXO locked by that script is spent. AFAIK, core-plutus is not Haskell, so the breakpoint will be ignored.